# How to disable scrolling on mobile Safari?

Tags: javascript, css, overflow, mobile-safari

I have a long page, and I want to hide the content that goes underneath the "fold", and it should work on iPhone/iPad.

`overflow:hidden` applied to `<body>` does not seem to work on mobile Safari.
I can't create a wrapper on the whole website to achieve that...

Do you know the solution?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

After many days trying, I found this solution that worked for me:

```
touch-action: none;
-ms-touch-action: none;
```

[MDN `touch-action` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action)

Comment: That didn't work for me on iOS 15.3.1, you used these rules on `body` right?

Comment: Update on my question: This seems to have worked when I added this in advance and not by using a class that toggles these rules on and off on the `body` element.

Comment: Note that while `touch-action` is set to `none`, touchscreen actions such as panning, pinch-to-zoom, etc. will likely be turned off. [MDN touch-action docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action)

Comment: I didn't test using a class to toggle these rules on and off through JavaScript. But using `el.style.touchAction = "none"` (and back to `""`) works on iOS 16.

Answer (score 142):

I had a similar issue and found that applying `overflow: hidden;` to both `html` and `body` solved my problem.

```
html,
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

For iOS 9, you may need to use this instead: *(Thanks chaenu!)*

```
html,
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work on iOS Safari. position: relative is also necessary.

Comment: Yes add both relative and overflow to html + body

Comment: A word of warning, overflow hidden on the <html> tag will break jQuery's scroll event

Comment: 2016: height: 100% is making vertical scrolling not smooth; is better to remove it.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on iOS 9, Safari. Body still scrollable, also after adding `position: relative`.

Comment: @Edo I finally got it by doing position: fixed + overflow hidden on body instead of relative. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Matt IIRC we also ran `position: fixed` for some time, but the downside is that that resets the scroll position.

Comment: `height: 100%` on both `html` and `body` fixed it for me on iOS 11.4.

Comment: @AlexHaas Neither position:relative nor height:100% works in IOS.. I wanted to stop body scroll when dragging an element in mobile . overflow:hidden works perfectly in Android phones. Is there any work around to solve this

Answer (score 98):

```
body {
  position:relative; // that's it
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: In my case adding "position: relative" didn't help but adding "position: fixed" worked.

Comment: Yip this worked. I'm building a site where they want the mobile nav to go over the content - but when it's open the content behind the nav in the background still scroll. 

The other answers with position, overflow & ***height*** also worked but with height the page jumps to the top when I open the nav. I guess it's unique to my situation but just thought I'd mention it in case anyone else with overlaid nav have the same problem.

Comment: Where does the wrapper go? How is this a complete answer?

Comment: Adding fixed position _does_ address the issue, but it makes the page jump to the top, which is bad for UX if you're implementing this in the background while you present a menu or modal. To make a good UX, you should, before locking position, store the scroll position of the page, and then re-apply it after unlocked.

Comment: In my case I had to add "width:100%" to get it working

Answer (score 34):

Some solutions listed here had some strange glitches when stretching the elastic scrolling. To fix that I used:

```
body.lock-position {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Source: http://www.teamtownend.com/2013/07/ios-prevent-scrolling-on-body/

Comment: This is nice (works better in my case than `position: relative`) however, the scroll position is lost after restoring default styling (e.g. closing menu).

Comment: For scroll position you can use js (jquery in this example) do something like this: 

  `// on menu open
  // save window pos
  $('body').attr( 'data-pos', $(window).scrollTop() ) ;
  // ...
  // on menu close
  // scroll to saved window pos
  $( window ).scrollTop( $('body').attr( 'data-pos' ) );`

Answer (score 12):

Had this issue today on iOS 8 & 9 and it seems that we now need to add height: 100%;

So add

```
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Its working in Safari browser.

```
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For me this:

```
height: 100%; 
overflow: hidden; 
width: 100%; 
position: fixed;
```

Wasn't enough, i't didn't work on iOS on Safari. I also had to add:

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

To make it work good. Works fine now :)

Answer (score 4):

Combining the answers and comments here and [this similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14270084/1184435) worked for me.

So posting as a whole answer.

Here's how you need to put a wrapper div around your site content, just inside the `<body>` tag.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <!-- other meta and head stuff here -->
 <head>
 <body>
     <div class="wrapper">
         <!-- Your site content here -->
     </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Create the wrapper class as below.

```
.wrapper{
    position:relative; //that's it
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

I also got the idea from [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14271049/1184435).

And [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24727026/1184435) also has got some food for thought. Something that probably will work equally good in both desktops and devices.

Comment: This causes the page to scroll to top for me when the modal gets closed.

Answer (score 2):

I've worked with `<body>`and `<div class="wrapper">`

**When popup opens ...**

`<body>` gets a height of 100% and an overflow:hidden

`<div class="wrapper">` gets position:relative;overflow:hidden;height:100%;

I use JS/jQuery to get the actual scrollposition of the page and store the value as data-attribut to body

Then i scroll to the scrollposition **in the .wrapper DIV** (not in window)

**Here is my solution:**

JS/jQuery:

```
// when popup opens

$('body').attr( 'data-pos', $(window).scrollTop()); // get actual scrollpos
$('body').addClass('locked'); // add class to body
$('.wrapper').scrollTop( $('body').attr( 'data-pos' ) ); // let wrapper scroll to scrollpos

// when popup close

$("body").removeClass('locked');
$( window ).scrollTop( $('body').attr( 'data-pos' ));
```

CSS:

```
body.locked {position:relative;overflow:hidden;height:100%;}
body.locked .wrapper {position:relative;overflow:hidden;height:100%;}
```

It works well on both sides ... desktop & mobile (iOS).

Answer (score 1):

```
html {
  position:relative;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  overflow:auto;
  height:auto
}
```

add this as default to your css

```
.class-on-html{
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:100%;
}
```

toggleClass this class to  to cut page

when you turn off this class first line will call scrolling bar back

Answer (score 0):

Why not wrap the content you don't want shown in an element with a class and set that class to `display:none` in a stylesheet meant only for the iphone and other handheld devices?

```
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="small-device.css" type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

It does apply, but it only applies to certain elements within the DOM.  for example, it won't work on a table, td, or some other elements, but it will work on a <DIV> tag.
eg:

```
<body>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>
```

Only tested in iOS 4.3.

A minor edit: you may be better off using overflow:scroll so two finger-scrolling does work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did: I check the body y position , then make the body fixed and adjust the top to the negative of that position. On reverse, I make the body static and set the scroll to the value I recorded before.

```
var body_x_position = 0;

function disable_bk_scrl(){

    var elb = document.querySelector('body');

    body_x_position = elb.scrollTop;
    // get scroll position in px

    var body_x_position_m = body_x_position*(-1);
    console.log(body_x_position);

    document.body.style.position = "fixed";

    $('body').css({ top: body_x_position_m });

}

function enable_bk_scrl(){  

    document.body.style.position = "static";

    document.body.scrollTo(0, body_x_position);

    console.log(body_x_position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A CSS keyword value that resets a property's value to the default specified by the browser in its UA stylesheet, as if the webpage had not included any CSS. For example, `display:revert` on a `<div>` would result in `display:block`.

```
overflow: revert;
```

*I think this will work properly*

Answer (score 0):

If you need scroll modal

Modal open

```
$('body').attr('data-position', $(window).scrollTop());
$('body').css({'overflow' : 'hidden', 'position' : 'fixed'});
```

Modal close

```
$('body').css({'overflow' : 'unset', 'position' : 'unset'});
$(window).scrollTop( $('body').attr( 'data-position' ));
```

Answer (score 0):

My version. Works in iOS

```js
 if (isModalWindowClose) {
        document.querySelector('body').style.overflow = '';
        document.querySelector('html').style.overflow = '';
        
        const scrollY = document.body.style.top;
        
        document.querySelector('html').style.height = '';
        document.body.style.position = '';
        document.body.style.left = '';
        document.body.style.top = '';

        window.scrollTo(0, parseInt(scrollY || '0') * -1);

        document.querySelector('html').style['scroll-behavior'] = '';
    } else {
        document.body.style.top = `-${window.scrollY}px`;
        document.querySelector('html').style.height = `${window.innerHeight - 1}px`;
        
        document.body.style.position = 'fixed';
        document.body.style.left = '0';
        
        document.querySelector('body').style.overflow = 'hidden';
        document.querySelector('html').style.overflow = 'hidden';
        
        document.querySelector('html').style['scroll-behavior'] = 'unset';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found many of these answers worked at first. But the moment the keyboard was initiated in iOS, it re-enabled the vertical scroll settings.

So I'm having to rebuild a new interface that is keyboardless.

Answer (score -6):

Simply change body height < 300px (height of mobile viewport on landspace is around 300px to 500px)

JS

```
$( '.offcanvas-toggle' ).on( 'click', function() {
    $( 'body' ).toggleClass( 'offcanvas-expanded' );
});
```

CSS

```
.offcanvas-expended { /* this is class added to body on click */
    height: 200px;
}
.offcanvas {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Not a very elegant solution, and will cause issues on iOS devices that are larger than the specific pixels you end up choosing. A different solution should be used.