# How to force tag to be width of viewport?

Tags: html, css, ipad, mobile, tablet

How do I get a tag, in this case the body tag, to only take up the size of the viewport even if it has a fixed width child?

example:
http://jsbin.com/ebusov

description: If I load the above link in Safari 5 and resize the browser I see the expected behavior.  A horizontal scroll bar does not appear.  The content that overflows the viewport is hidden.  If I load this in an ipad the overflowing content is visible and causes scroll bars.

desired outcome: Scroll bars should never show up, including on the iPad.

actual result: On the iPad, and possibly other devices, overflowing content is visible and the user can scroll to the left.

How can I hide content that overflows the viewport with fixed width elements?

Comment: Why don't  you just use CSS media queries? This way you can make sure you are preparing the best experience to the user according to its setup. Here is a good writeup if needed: http://thinkvitamin.com/design/getting-started-and-gotchas-of-css-media-queries/

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047337/does-overflowhidden-applied-to-body-work-on-iphone-safari

Comment: I want the element to overflow the viewable viewport, but I don't want the user to be able to scroll the entire layout viewport.  Reference: [A Tale of Two Viewports](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/05/a_tale_of_two_v.html).

Answer (score 0):

try this in your body tag:

```
<body style="overflow:hidden;">
```

Comment: That's what his example has. The question is not how to do it, but how to make it function on an iPad too!