# Overflow-x:hidden doesn't prevent content from overflowing in mobile browsers

Tags: css, overflow, viewport, mobile-browser

I have a website [here](http://02b23fa.netsolhost.com/wordpress1/).

Viewed in a desktop browser, the black menu bar properly extends only to edge of the window, since the `body` has `overflow-x:hidden`.

In any mobile browser, whether Android or iOS, the black menu bar displays its full width, which brings whitespace on the right of the page.  As far as I can tell, this whitespace isn't even a part of the `html` or `body` tags.

Even if I set the viewport to a specific width in the `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1100, initial-scale=1">
```

The site expands to the 1100px but still has the whitespace beyond the 1100.

What am I missing?  How do I keep the viewport to 1100 and cut off the overflow?

Comment: This is especially an issue in iOS9

Answer (score 365, accepted):

Creating a site wrapper div inside the `<body>` and applying the `overflow-x:hidden` to the *wrapper* instead of the `<body>` or `<html>` fixed the issue.

It appears that browsers that parse the `<meta name="viewport">` tag simply ignore `overflow` attributes on the `html` and `body` tags.

Note: You may also need to add `position: relative` to the wrapper div.

Comment: I found that in addition to setting the `overflow` to `hidden`, I had to set the `position` to `fixed`...

Comment: For me, just adding `overflow-x: hidden` to the first `div` inside `body` worked just fine. No need to add another `div`, just try to set it to your outermost `div`.

Comment: Adding position to fixed stops me from being able to scroll!

Comment: Adding a wrapper div with overflow: hidden did the trick for me in iOS7!

Comment: I tried, I put all my code inside a div and give it overflow-x:hidden but doens't work, I add  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 too but nothing changed :/ any ideas?

Comment: Making a div wrapper around everything in <body> works.

Comment: Wasn't working for me on MobileSafari (iOS9) until I ensured the viewport meta tag looked like this: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">` - at issue here: changing the main content container can cause a big change in document height, which in turn can cause weird zooming behavior.

Comment: @leepowers `overflow-x: hidden` is still not working for me even after I add this meta tag. Could you please share a link to your website where it is working?

Comment: overflow: hidden; height: 100%; together works for me

Comment: Definitely ^ if you find an element outside of that region make sure it's not set to absolute but instead set to fixed.

Comment: @theorise nothing worked but the `position: fixed`. thank you <33

Comment: Hey gang, when I found that `position:relative` works as well.

Comment: `overflow: scroll` if you want the user to still be able to see the overflowed content

Comment: I have tried this for my ionic app (only for iOs Devices) but it's not working for any position of body content.

Comment: You saved me man, God knows I have this problem working on since last 3 hours

Thank You 1M

Comment: Fixed the issue for me as well. Relative positioning for the div wrapper was not needed in my case.

Comment: Update - Relative positioning was important after-all! Without it, landscape orientation on mobile browsers broke the layout.

Comment: te amo breoooooh <33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333

Comment: Hey great answer, though  this solves the initial problem, but for any of you got a sticky nav, this makes it not stick anymore! I solved it by putting the sticky nav outside of the wrapper!

Comment: I initially thought this worked, but that was not the case. Most of these answers address the *symptoms* of the problem. The best solution seems to be to [fix the *cause* of the problem (the `<meta name="viewport">` tag)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36693202/114558).

Comment: @rinogo The `<meta name="viewport">` solution addresses the symptoms as well. Because the horizontal scrollbar still appears, the user just can't scroll, which isn't a perfect solution.

Answer (score 108):

try

```
html, body {
  overflow-x:hidden 
}
```

instead of just

```
body {
  overflow-x:hidden 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the application of `overflow` anything to `html` and/or `body` in any combination didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Sorry that it didn't work out for you. Before I answered I made a quick test using your site and applying my suggestion to your css. It fixed the problem for the standard- and dolphin browser on my android phone at least.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what do you use to modify css on your mobile browsers?

Comment: I dont know if that is possible. I'm also looking for a mobile browser with some sort of developer plugin :) In your case I just downloaded part of your site to make the changes locally on my pc, then uploaded it onto my webserver - very annoying workaround ;)

Comment: Worked for me. http://eduardd.eu/projects/ezo ( between 480 and 992px footer had a problem with that overflowing image of the woman and towels )

Comment: Does anyone know why this works, when specifying body{} and html{} separately doesnt?

Comment: In needed to add `height:100%;` as well, otherwise vertical scroll would not work properly on pages with loading images (which make the page grow in height).

Comment: This worked for me when also including `position: relative` on `body`.

Answer (score 78):

[VictorS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/407615/victor-s)'s comment on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14271049/444382) deserves to be it's own answer because it's a very elegant solution that does, indeed work. And I'll add a tad to it's usefulness.

Victor notes adding `position:fixed` works.

```
body.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
}
```

And indeed it does. However, it also has a slight side-affect of essentially scrolling to the top. `position:absolute` resolves this but, re-introduces the ability to scroll on mobile.

If you know your viewport ([my plugin for adding viewport to the `<body>`](https://github.com/will-e-yams/yams.viewport)) you can just add a css toggle for the `position`.

```
body.modal-open {
    // block scroll for mobile;
    // causes underlying page to jump to top;
    // prevents scrolling on all screens
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
}
body.viewport-lg {
    // block scroll for desktop;
    // will not jump to top;
    // will not prevent scroll on mobile
    position: absolute; 
}
```

---

I also add this to prevent the underlying page from jumping left/right when showing/hiding modals.

```
body {
    // STOP MOVING AROUND!
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get the mobile part to not jump to top?

Comment: What worked for me was turning the element that was supposed to be hidden by overflow from position: absolute to position: fixed. Thankfully.

Comment: @WraithKenny -  If you want the page to prevent jumping to the top on a mobile device, you can use the following hack'ish/ugly approach. Inside your modal function, make sure you get the current scroll offset before doing anything, than apply the modal style together and also set the top margin of your body equal to the minus of the current offset. Make sure when you remove the modal you, set the margin back to 0 and scroll the page back to the original offset.

Comment: This solution only works in case your modal's content fits into the screen, i.e. you don't require to scroll the modal itself.

Comment: There are other fixed and absolute positioned elements on my page as well. Making body `position:fixed or absolute` disturbing their positions as well. Not suitable/working in my case :(

Comment: I think this answers a different question than I intended to ask, but it answers it well.  I hadn't intended the question to be about modals, but rather about any arbitrary element on a page overflowing.  So `position:fixed` wouldn't be appropriate on many of those elements.  The original question didn't really specify that though, so I still think this answer is very helpful.

Answer (score 54):

As @Indigenuity states, this appears to be caused by browsers parsing the `<meta name="viewport">` tag.

To solve this problem at the source, try the following:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">`.

In my tests this prevents the user from zooming out to view the overflowed content, and as a result prevents panning/scrolling to it as well.

Comment: Adding `initial-scale=1` to an existing viewport metatag does indeed fix the problem. Thanks!

Comment: For me it was the `minimum-scale=1` that fixed it

Comment: This is what actually worked for me after trying everything else. Thanks a lot !

Comment: It helps, but not preventing horizontal scrollbar on mobile yet.

Comment: Wew, thanks for this. This happened in my case. Only on media queries the whitespaces appear on bottom and right side. You bro deserve a million + and thanks

Comment: Much better than the other solutions here - fixing the cause of the problem instead of a symptom. Thanks!

Comment: For me this seems to not solve the problem on Chrome Modile

Comment: Wow thanks! The other suggestions were a bit bulky, and I was glad to find such a simple solution. :)

Comment: Any reason this is not the accepted answer? This should be the accepted solution IMO, OP even referenced meta tags. Other solutions strike me as too hacky.

Comment: This seems to solve the issue for me but now instead of zooming out I can horizontally scroll the whole screen and there's no content to the right... any ideas?

Answer (score 41):

This is the simplest solution to solve horisontal scrolling in Safari.

```
html, body {
  position:relative;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Comment: It seems to work. But do you have an explanation why this works?

Comment: No, it finally didn't work. I ended up doing the math and made sure that div's aren't wider than allowed, css calc() helped me here a lot as it allows the mixture of relative widths (vw or %) and absolute widths (px).

Comment: Ofcourse this is something of a workaround. There is still something overflowing somewhere, it's just cut off now. Try adding a css rule: * { outline: 1px solid red; }
If you still can't find the overflowing element, then it's probably caused by a margin somewhere. Try adding * { margin:0 !IMPORTANT; }
and see if the overflow disappears.

Comment: Works for me. Interesting that the hidden element changes the body's width. For me, however, this is the case for ALL Safari browsers, not only the mobile ones. Just had to fix a Bootstrap 4 `table-responsive` Bug. This was the solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what the guy who said this doesn't work was doing wrong (maybe didn't refresh his cache). This solution absolutely does work.

Comment: This is the only thing that helped me hide an absolutely positioned element which animates offscreen

Comment: I can't believe this is still a problem in 2019.  But the solution above totally worked.  Thx.

Comment: A problem with setting `overflow-x: hidden` on `body` is that `position: sticky` stops working.

Comment: This solution is not working in IOS 13.0 or above devices. Any solution ?

Answer (score 16):

```
body{
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden !important;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
```

works on iOS9

Comment: It does work, but putting position:fixed to your body does make you scroll to top

Comment: Weird but it worked for me without fixed position, also. Only one from all the solutions here!

Comment: Only one that worked for me,   using chrom and boostrap + angularJS

Answer (score 6):

> Creating a site wrapper div inside the body and applying the overflow->x:hidden to the wrapper INSTEAD of the body or html fixed the issue.

This worked for me after also adding `position: relative` to the wrapper.

Comment: This worked for me. The side effect was that I've got two scroll bars instead of one. The solution was to make it `overflow: hidden` instead of `overflow-x: hidden`. Works on mobile Safari, Chrome, IE11 on OSX and Win.

Answer (score 5):

Keep the viewport untouched: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Assuming you would like to achieve the effect of a continuous black bar to the right side: `#menubar` shouldn't exceed **100%**, adjust the **border radius** such that the right side is squared and adjust the padding so that it extends a little more to the right. Modify the following to your `#menubar`:

```
border-radius: 30px 0px 0px 30px;
width: 100%; /*setting to 100% would leave a little space to the right */
padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px; /*fills the little gap*/
```

Adjusting the `padding` to 10px of course leaves the left menu to the edge of the bar, you can put the remaining **40px** to each of the `li`, **20px** on each side left and right:

```
.menuitem {
display: block;
padding: 0px 20px;
}
```

When you resize the browser smaller, you would find still the white background: place your background texture instead from your div to `body`. Or alternatively, adjust the navigation menu width from 100% to lower value using media queries. There are a lot of adjustments to be made to your code to create a proper layout, I'm not sure what you intend to do but the above code will somehow fix your overflowing bar.

Comment: if you use `box-sizing: border-box;` you can add padding to a 100% width div.

Answer (score 5):

No previous single solution worked for me, I had to mix them and got the issue fixed also on older devices (iphone 3).

First, I had to wrap the html content into an outer div:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">... old html goes here ...</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then I had to apply overflow hidden to the wrapper, because overflow-x was not working:

```
  #wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

and this fixed the issue.

Comment: How is this different to @Indigenuity's answer?

Comment: @ian Kemp overflow: hidden != overflow-x: hidden

Answer (score 4):

Adding a wrapper `<div>` around the entirety of your content will indeed work. While semantically "icky", I added an div with a class of overflowWrap right inside the `body` tag and then set set my CSS like this:

```
html, body, .overflowWrap {
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Might be overkill now, but works like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same problem with Android devices but not iOS devices. Managed to resolve by specifying position:relative in the outer div of the absolutely positioned elements (with overflow:hidden for outer div)

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue by using overflow-x:hidden; as follows

```
@media screen and (max-width: 441px){

#end_screen { (NOte:-the end_screen is the wrapper div for all other div's inside it.)
  overflow-x: hidden;
   }
 }
```

structure is as follows

`1st div end_screen >> inside it >> end_screen_2(div) >> inside it >> end_screen_2.`

`'end_screen is the wrapper of end_screen_1 and end_screen_2 div's`

Answer (score 3):

As subarachnid said overflow-x hidden for both body and html worked
Here's working example

```
**HTML**
<div class="contener">
  <div class="menu">
  das
  </div>
  <div class="hover">
    <div class="img1">
    First Strip
    </div>
     <div class="img2">
    Second Strip
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="baner">
dsa
</div>

**CSS**
body, html{
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
body{
  margin:0;
}
.contener{
  width:100vw;
}
.baner{
   background-image: url("http://p3cdn4static.sharpschool.com/UserFiles/Servers/Server_3500628/Image/abstract-art-mother-earth-1.jpg");
   width:100vw;
   height:400px;
   margin-left:0;
   left:0;
}
.contener{
  height:100px;
}
.menu{
  display:flex;
  background-color:teal;
  height:100%;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  align:content:bottom;
}
.img1{
  width:150px;
  height:25px;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  background-color:red;
  position:absolute;
  top:40px;
  right:-50px;
  line-height:25px;
  padding:0 20px;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  transition:all 0.4s;
}
.img2{
  width:190px;
  text-align:center;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  background-color:#333;
  position:absolute;
  height:25px;
  line-height:25px;
  top:55px;
  right:-50px;
  padding:0 20px;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:white;
  transition:all 0.4s;
}
.hover{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.hover:hover .img1{
  background-color:#333;
  transition:all 0.4s;
}
.hover:hover .img2{
  background-color:blue;
  transition:all 0.4s;
}
```

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkqyka7n/1/)

Answer (score 3):

I had tried many ways from replies in this topic, mostly works but got some side-effect like if I use overflow-x on `body,html` it might slow/freeze the page when users scroll down on mobile.

use `position: fixed` on wrapper/div inside the body is good too, but when I have a menu and use Javascript click animated scroll to some section, It's not working.

So, I decided to use `touch-action: pan-y pinch-zoom` on wrapper/div inside the body. Problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

easiest way to solve this , add

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">`

Comment: You should absolutely never prevent the user from zooming.

Answer (score 1):

I've just been working on this for a few hours, trying various combinations of things from this and other pages. The thing that worked for me in the end was to make a site wrapper div, as suggested in the accepted answer, but to set both overflows to hidden instead of just the x overflow. If I leave overflow-y at scroll, I end up with a page that only scrolls vertically by a few pixels and then stops.

```
#all-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Just this was enough, without setting anything on the body or html elements.

Answer (score 1):

Solution that properly work for mobile device with flex positionning top :

```
html,body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

and in web page :

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=0">
```

Don't forget to positioning this css in the different webpage main divs :

```
height : auto !important;
```

Answer (score 1):

`html, body{ overflow-x: hidden; position: relative; }` Just try like this where you have added the overflow-hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Setting overflow-x to 'clip' instead of 'hidden' also prevents unwanted scrolling on touch-devices, with wacom-pens, with shift-scrollwheel or any other programmatic scrolling. On the downside, it also prevents programmatic scrolling with javascript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#clip

Answer (score 0):

The only way to fix this issue for my bootstrap modal (containing a form) was to add the following code to my CSS:

```
.modal {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

step 1: set position to fixed to the element that goes out from the viewport. In my case it is:

```
.nav-links {
    position:fixed;
    right:0px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0, 0.8);
    height:85vh;
    top:8vh;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items: center;
    width:40%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

Step2: add a css property to body and html as:

```
body, html{
    overflow-x:  hidden;
}
```

I didn't add any wrapper. Only these two steps worked for me. The project I am working on is an angular project.

Answer (score 0):

The following works

```
body,
.innerbodywrapper{
overflow-x: hidden;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was occurring in mobile Chrome browsers. Adding this to `head` fixed it for me:

```html
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <style>
    html,
    body {
      width: 100%;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      position: relative;
    }
  </style>
```

Creating a div and applying these to it instead of body didn't change anything so I went with not having unnecessary elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
.App {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
}
```

This helped me. I wanted to avoid the vertical scrolling of a react App.