# White space to the right on smaller screens (iPhone, Android, etc)

Tags: html, iphone, css

I'm facing an issue where our [dev site](http://dev.autopartsnetwork.com) is experiencing issues for mobile devices. We're going to be making the site responsive but in the meantime, would like it to appear scaled appropriately for the screen size. The main issue right now is white spacing on the right which may be occurring due to fixed image sizes in the CSS (such as the shadow under the slider), but I'm wondering if I really must remove these to make it render properly.

I've also tried the following, to no avail...

html {
overflow-x: hidden;
}

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overflow-x:hidden doesn't prevent content from overflowing in mobile browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270084/overflow-xhidden-doesnt-prevent-content-from-overflowing-in-mobile-browsers)