# bootstraps 3 white space on right side mobile devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am getting a white space while scrolling to the right on a mobile device. Desktop browsing works as it should. I've tried the following things, non have worked.

css:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;    <- Don't like this one, would rather have it visible
}
```

html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Shall I just try disabling horizontal scrolling?

Tool used for testing: http://mattkersley.com/responsive/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found out that `overflow-x:hidden;` works as it should if put into `#intro` class which wraps whole page content.

Found solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14271049/410624