# X-axis not disappearing after hiding, still works on mobile view

Tags: html, css, web

So I've been recently working on a website and have been experiencing small bugs. One of which has really been an issue in fixing, the other I will discuss on another forum.

The x-axis is not hiding, even after hiding in CSS, this is a real issue.
It works on laptops, just not in the mobile view.

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
     overflow-y: auto;
     max-width: 100%;
}
```

My website address for this issue is:

http://www.theeventlister.com/landingpage/events/uk/boardmasters.html

Comment: Did you try with `html,body { overflow-x:hidden} ` . So also the `html` ?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, yes tried with that also, still not working, unfortunately, will keep working to see how this can be fixed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overflow-x:hidden; on mobile device not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193272/overflow-xhidden-on-mobile-device-not-working)

Comment: Hi, thank you, no duplicates, ill make sure to double check across.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the following code:

```
     body, html {
     height: 100%;
     }
```

Overrides this code :

```
    body {
     font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
     position: fixed;
     font-weight: 400;
     font-size: 1.125rem;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     overflow-x: hidden;
     overflow-y: auto;
    }
```

Simply add overflow-x: hidden; to the first code and it will work :

```
body, html {
height: 100%;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```