HTML Input Disable Scroll
I have a readonly input. And there is a long value inside. I have overflow-x: hidden; on it but i still can scroll in mobile devices. I don't want this behavior. How can i disable input scroll ? Thanks for help.
CodeSandbox :
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-select-blur-onchange-forked-5lt4y5?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js
For Get Same Behavior :
Open Sandbox, Inspect page, open mobile view, hold on input and its scrollable.
Simple Code Example :
<div style={{ width: "200px" }}>
      <input
        style={{
          overflowX: "hidden",
        }}
        value=" TEST TTESTEST TEST TEST TEST TEST"
      />
</div>


Is the value in the input supposed to be read-only?

Similar question but not quite a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193272/overflow-xhidden-on-mobile-device-not-working (it's focused on the body tag, but may also help for your situation)

@Hilory Yes. Unfortunately it supposed to be. And i can't change input to another element too.

@DanielBeck thanks for help! But i saw it before i open topic. I tried but its not help. I think overflow hidden in input doesn't work as body.

You could make a workaround by limiting the "maxlength" attribute of the input.

Few solutions :

Add disabled to your input
Add pointer-events: none; to your input style


I thinks that's not possible on a -element.

@Jonas I think so. I will use pointer-event:none as Loic's comment i guess. Thank you guys for help.

Since the input is disabled, you can add pointer-events property in your CSS to prevent it from being focusable
input{
 pointer-events: none;
}


I think that this is what you're trying to achieve
<div style={{ width: '200px' }}>
    <input disabled
        style={{ pointerEvents: 'none' }}
        value=" TEST TTESTEST TEST TEST TEST TEST"
    />
</div>


Even when overflow-x: hidden is applied, scrolling within a readonly input element on mobile devices can be prevented by applying additional CSS to completely stop the scrolling function. Using pointer-events: none on the input is one useful strategy that not only stops scrolling but also disables all other interactions, such as text selection.
<div style={{ width: "200px" }}>
  <input
    style={{
      overflowX: "hidden",
      pointerEvents: "none"
    }}
    readOnly
    value=" TEST TTESTEST TEST TEST TEST TEST"
  />
</div>

