# When using scrollme js script it gives scroll left to right on mobiles

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

Hi when using the scrollme script I get a scroll left to right when viewing on mobiles.

You can view the script here:

http://scrollme.nckprsn.com/

I have used the overflow-x:hidden on the body but it still gives a scroll effect from left to right.

Here is the body css:

```css
body{
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background-color:#f6f6f6;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    color:#727272;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

I have tried everything I can think of but the scroll effect does not go away.

If anyone can shed some light I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it is the body which has the scrollbar, and not something like a div which contains the content?

Comment: more code would help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[Overflow-x:hidden doesn't prevent content from overflowing in mobile browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270084/overflow-xhidden-doesnt-prevent-content-from-overflowing-in-mobile-browsers)

> Creating a site wrapper div inside the body and applying the overflow-x:hidden to the wrapper INSTEAD of the body or html fixed the issue.
>
> It appears that browsers that parse the  tag simply ignore overflow attributes on the html and body tags.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `overflow: hidden !important`?

In most cases, the `!important` usually overrides other CSS code that is telling it to do otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

On mobile:

```javascript
 var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width
 $("body").css("max-width",width);
```

CSS:

```css
body{
    width : 100%
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background-color:#f6f6f6;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    color:#727272;
    overflow-x:hidden !important;
}
```