# Overflow-X Hidden on html tag, iOS Safari Lags

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

On  a simple mobile page, i tested on iOS safari have some overflow div using

```
div {position:absolute; right:-2em; /* or */ left: -3em;}
```

if i set the body using

```
body {width:100%; overflow-x: hidden;}
```

it only hide the scroll bar, but still able to pan to the right;
but if I do

```
html {overflow-x: hidden;}
```

it dose the trick but make scrolling very laggy. prob something simple that i overlooked.
thanks

[image]

Comment: This answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46039555/502846

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT:***

sorry I didnt read your question correctly but try changing the block's position to this instead:

```
position:fixed;
```

it does what you want but that block will stay in that spot when you scroll up and down.

 try that and see if it is what you wanted.

Comment: I am trying to prevent it to scroll to the right of my 100% width.

Comment: I'm very sorry I did not read it correctly. one way that will work is changing the block that is position:absolute; to position:fixed; although it works for what you want it fixes it in that spot when you scroll up and down. try that and see if that helps.