# overflow-x:hidden does not work on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I built a one-page site which works fine, except for one thing (on mobile devices), which is the `overflow-x:hidden`.

I use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height"/>`.

and when I searched I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270084/overflow-xhidden-doesnt-prevent-content-from-overflowing-in-mobile-browsers) issue 
so I create site wrapper div inside the body and applying the overflow-x:hidden to the wrapper. but still have problem in mobile and tablet device.

my website is [here](http://carpediem.ir/asrnovin/payamap/).

Comment: Your website seemed to scroll fine on my LG G3 Android phone.  There was no sideways scrolling or anything, and the `overflow-x` seemed to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me too on Samsung galaxy s5. Might sound silly but it isn't just cached on your devices is it since before you added the wrapper and overflow-x: hidden? I had to clear my phone cache a lot when I was updating my site recently.

Comment: I solve the problem. changing style of clouds help me to solve it