# HTML body not filling complete width on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile

If I open my (GWT) page in a normal browser, everything works fine. The body takes the whole width and the content is nicely centered. But if I try this on a mobile phone, the body does not take the whole width and therefore the content is not centered.

I couldn't find out why it is being displayed like this. Also, adding 100% width to body and html tag does not solve the issue .

Is there a way to get this working nicely on a mobile device?

The page can be reached under: http://www.vegantastic.de/
[image]

Comment: For starters, use this viewport tag: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: @APAD1: That made it better: http://2.vegantastic0.appspot.com/

Comment: You're using pixel widths throughout your page IDs and classes. If you want fluid design, you need to use percent-based widths so the page can adapt.

Comment: Jesus Christ, this is 2 years old and the issue still exist in Chrome.

Answer (score 86):

this was driving me crazy and i just solved it by adding `position:fixed` to the body

Comment: Not sure why this works, but fixed the problem for me.  Thanks for posting.

Comment: Yep, this fixes the issue for me too! Note though that `position: fixed;` disables scrolling. If you need that then use `position: absolute;` instead.

Comment: `position: absolute;` actually worked (I had to specify `width: 100vw;` as well) – but is there any "nice & clean" solution?

Comment: This is not a very nice solution (even though it might work). It forces the body to expand, rather than solve the problem.

Comment: @dma_k I added a somewhat nicer answer (if it helps in your case)

Comment: It doesn't work for me if I set position to relative or absolute. Proper solution was commenting out html until you find element that overflows over 100% and causes everything to get scaled down.

Comment: I added `position: fixed` to the `html` instead of the body.

Comment: Don't use this approach. When this happens one of the elements inside your body is breaking the window by probably using a negative margin or something like that. Open inspect element of your browser and delete elements one by one to find out which element is causing the problem.

Comment: In my case, I have the div.parent with `position: relative;`, and inside of div.parent I have div.child with `position:absolute;` + some `transform: transition(-50%,-50%);`. For div.parent I needed to set the `overflow-x: hidden;` that solved my issue.           In chrome browser you can check it by going to `devtools` and console `window.visualViewport.scale`, For me, it retunred 0.85; after I added the `overflow-x: hidden;` for my div.parent it became 1.0

Comment: I did `position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0` for a doc that wants to scroll vertically

Comment: Do not use this approach! See Ali's (and JoKr's) answer, in my case, I had a div with a greater width than the mobile view's width and an element with a negative `right` property that spilt out the body width.

Answer (score 64):

## Why is `body` not full width, even though its set to 100% / vw?

In a strange way it **is** full width, but the viewport is scaled down automatically by the browser, so it fits in the overflowing content.

To check, if this is the case, type this in the console *(1)*: `window.visualViewport.scale`

*1) edit Sep. 2019: [visualViewport: only available on Chrome](https://caniuse.com/#search=visualViewport) - sry for late notice*

If it returns something like **0.8**, then the body size is correct, but the viewport is scaled down.

You can also double tap to toggle between *scale 1* and *"fit-content-scale"* *(needs touch simulation like in chrome dev-tools)*.

## How to not overflow `body`?

- See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14271049/3313410 "Creating a site wrapper div inside the body"
- or check, if a certain element has a `min-width`, that "overrides" its `width`
- or check, if something is rotated, or margins out https://stackoverflow.com/a/45534745/3313410

Comment: Thanks,  the article you linked had the answer for me. Putting overflow-x:hidden inside a parent div of the badly behaving child element, stopped it from overflowing to the right angle and messing up the layout.

Comment: Thanks! Wrapper div inside body with overflow-x:hidden, solved it for me.

Answer (score 36):

It might be because of a very long word on your webpage. After using the correct viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width">
```

I tried this out, by placing this text inside a paragraph element, inside some empty HTML document:

```html
<p>Here I have a text, and I am going to use a very long, and not-imaginary word (oh it's real) inside. Without some word-breaking CSS, the result will break the screen on smaller devices: Pseudopseudohypoparathyroidism</p>
```

What happened when I decreased the screen size without the mobile phone simulator:

[image: Decreased screen size without mobile phone simulator]

And what happened when I decreased the screen size with the mobile phone simulator:

[image: Decreased screen size with mobile phone simulator]

Quite the difference. My tip: use the following CSS attribute:

```
p {
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! FYI, the viewport META alone was enough to fix the shrunk view width due to long URLs. Interestingly, my old (Gingerbread) WebKit (just like any of the desktop browsers, of course) doesn't have this shrunk-width problem: back in the days the viewport width could be just fine, while wrapping those long URLs. I wonder why the new default behavior is preferred today.

Answer (score 7):

I can see that the problem behind this question was solved, but I just experienced the same issue and the answer here could not applied in my case because of the scroll disabling stated in the comment, and any other style modifications on the body seemed to affect the result.

After experimentation I found out this was caused by an element inside my page which was rotated and its height became an obstacle on mobile, since it was closer the right end of the body.

So I would like to add this answer if someone, like myself, find this question via google:

This problem can be caused by many factors, you may want to investigate if one of your component's width is not becoming a problem on mobile view. There is probably a div too long on your page, or a rotated one which margin got out of the body.

Comment: same problem here, an image with rotation was out of the viewport.
added ```overflow-x: hidden;``` to HTML, solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 6):

Just add this to your body tag and your problem should be solved:

```css
body {
  position: absolute;
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain solution please?

Answer (score 4):

In my case, body (and html) element returns to normal after removing the properties from `display: flex;` group. After my investigation, I discovered that every element with an automatically calculated width must be in an element that has height and width and wraps all children going all the way to the body. After adding some `overflow:auto; position:relative;` to the parent elements, the body scales correctly with display flex nested in display flex.

```
@import '../../variables.scss';
:host {
  overflow: auto; // added this line
}

.top-bar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: $shadow;
    position: relative;
    .search-item {
        flex: 1;
        margin: 0 1em;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        position: relative;
        input {
            margin: 0;
            border-top-right-radius: 0px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
            border-right-width: 0px;
            flex: 1;
            width: 1px;
        }
        button {
            margin: 0;
            border-top-left-radius: 0px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-left-width: 0px;
            box-shadow: inset $shadow;
        }
    }
    button.icon-only {
        border: none;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
}
```

**menu looks like this:**

[image: menu]

**before:**
[image: before]

**after:**
[image: after]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case there was a `grid` element that had many columns and `grid-gap` set to `50px`. It caused `html` to expand. I think it's a good practice to reduce `grid-column-gap` on small screens.

Comment: I can reproduce the overflow with grid-gap (+1)
https://jsfiddle.net/94y1b7qu/
 ...though it might be another idea to use fractional units (fr) instead, or review the sum of cell-width + gap-width so it is below 100vw (in demo the sum is 125vw), or create multiple layouts with media-queries (e.g. single column for mobile)...