# Hidden overflow showing in mobile browser but not in Desktop Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Here are the screenshots of my mobile browser and my desktop browser.

My webpage has some overflow in x axis which I hid using **overflow-x: hidden;**

Is there any way I can make my webpage render in mobile browser, the way it renders in desktop browser i.e. full width and overflow hidden.

CSS:

```
body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background-image:url(../images/PaperBG/goovepaper.png);
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is CSS of your body?

Comment: @MartinSzabo I updated the question with CSS

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overflow-x:hidden doesn't prevent content from overflowing in mobile browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270084/overflow-xhidden-doesnt-prevent-content-from-overflowing-in-mobile-browsers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
 #main_body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are having an issue with the markup, check for overflowing contents,you can use the mozilla dev tool to get a 3D view of the page and fix the overflowing contents towards x axis. If it still doesn't help, please provide a sample markup on jsfiddle, codepoen or somewhere, we can have a look.