# Safari overflow-x hidden causes fixed elements inside to mess up

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I am implementing a trick to stop side scrolling for Safari using what I found from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270084/overflow-xhidden-doesnt-prevent-content-from-overflowing-in-mobile-browsers).

Essentially, I'm putting `overflow-x: hidden;` on an overall wrapper div instead of `body` and `head`. It effectively stops side scrolling but then it causes a div inside of that wrapper to loose it's fixed property. Specifically, I have a div that usually acts as a side sticky nav but it only activates it's fixed property at a certain scroll height.

[This is the page](http://cedricith.com/projects/communicaid.html) I'm doing this for.

---

To recreate this effect, do the following in inspector:

1. add a wrapper `div` around everything
2. set that div to `overflow-x: hidden;` `height: 100%;` and `position: fixed`
3. scroll down and you'll see the sidenav isn't fixed to the page.

**How do I fix this?**

Comment: If the wrapper is positioned fixed without overflow-y:auto I can't event scroll down. Do you have more logic to inject the wrapper in Safari only?

Comment: @zoku, the height has to be 100%. And overflow-y doesn't even have to be set to auto

Comment: Ah! I see what you did there! I think you might want to revise your Javascript for the handling of the sticky navigation. Please see the edit of my answer below for details.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this first:

> You could try to use:
>
> ```
> .wrapper {
>     position: absolute;
>     width: 100%;
>     overflow-x: hidden;
> }
> ```
>
> on your div. That worked for me in Safari for Windows (terribly old
>   Version, though).

Your Javascript checks for `$(document).scrollTop();`, but when your content is in a container of 100% height the scrollTop of $(document) will always be 0. Try `$('.yourWrapperDiv').scrollTop();` instead. This could work.