# overflow-x: hidden; not working (mobile)

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

The `overflow-x` is working fine in Desktop, but when it runs in mobile and tablets, it doesn't work.

I know it's because of the images, but I want to display them that way on the mobile view, but it scroll horizontally to display the rest parts of the image.

How do I force `hidden overflow-x`? (didn't work either with `!important`)
I also tried width and height of 100%!

https://jsfiddle.net/4wqx2f0k/

Please check the site on mobile: http://urbanphenomena.net.projects/urbanBeta

Comment: Set the image width to 100%.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270084/overflow-xhidden-doesnt-prevent-content-from-overflowing-in-mobile-browsers
Did you see this?

Comment: Yeah, but it didn't help me @GeethuNimesh

Comment: maybe if you remove `width: 100%` it will work

Comment: Definitely a duplicate.  The answer is:

    html, body {
      overflow-x:hidden;
      position:relative;
    }