# Overflow: hidden not working in ios safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, safari, overflow

Setting overflow hidden to `html, body` using jquery or css does not work in ios safari but works on safari on mac and all other browsers.

I tried looking for answers here : [Overflow-x:hidden doesn't prevent content from overflowing in mobile browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270084/overflow-xhidden-doesnt-prevent-content-from-overflowing-in-mobile-browsers). The answer explains to use a wrapper div with `position: relative` and add `overflow: hidden` to that div. This solution did not work for me.

There is also an answer which says to use `position: fixed` but the problem i have is that i need to use `toggleClass` to toggle between the overflows for a popup message to work but when i apply it using jquery the screen scrolls all the way up to the top.

I also tried adding a transparent `position: fixed` overlay with full width and height behind the popup but weirdly enough, the body/html in the background can still be scrolled through the overlay.

The issue can be seen on my website while in responsive mode by clicking the bottom right share button here: https://ph4ntom.tech/downloads/wallpapers/wallpapers.html

Would there be a working way to hide/disable the overlay using jquery/css/html temporarily on event in ios safari?

i did not include the whole code because it would make the question longer and more confusing and i dont think including the code is necessary as my question only demands for a  way to hide overflow or disable scrolling in ios safari where using `overflow: hidden` on `body, html` does not work. Please read : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Thankyou for the help :)

Comment: please add your code so we can check what is going wrong. thanks

Comment: i dont think the whole code is necessary because it will only make the question longer. its simply `$(this).on("click", function(){$("html, body").toggleClass("hideOverflow")})`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("body").toggleClass("overflow-hidden")
})
```

```css
.overflow-hidden {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: i apologize. i explained my issue in the very first line. Adding `overflow hidden` to `body, html` in any way simply does not work in ios safari. I thought that was clear enough