# Overflow:hidden not working on mobile App

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

I am using CSS property `overflow:hidden` to stop the scrolling on my mobile app. It's not working on IOS App, Safari Browser and Android app, but this code is working on android Browser:

```
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Try adding: position: fixed;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3047337/6191987

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does overflow:hidden applied to <body> work on iPhone Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047337/does-overflowhidden-applied-to-body-work-on-iphone-safari)

Answer (score 0):

Add Site wrapper after body tag

```
.siteWrap{
       position: fixed;
       overflow-x: hidden;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       overflow-y: scroll !important;
   }
```