# Hide horizontal off-screen overflow of a div that has a large width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I hide the horizontal, off-screen overflow of a `<div>` that has a large width set on it? For example:

HTML:

```
<div class="example">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.example {
  height: 100px;
  width: 10000px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[Here is an example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uh8d2avo/5/) that shows the scrollbar appearing, I wish for that to not happen if the div is very large like this.

**Edit**: Adding hidden overflow-x on the parent element does not work on small width iOS devices.

Comment: You mean the window scroll bar?

Comment: body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

Comment: Helpful hint: you're on the right track with the `overflow: hidden;`, but this sets the overflow to hide for anything *inside* of the `.example` container. You need to set the `overflow: hidden` property on the container that the `.example` `div` is in. Plus, if it's only *horizontal* overflow you want to hide, then you need to use `overflow-x`, as suggested above.

Comment: try here for the ios https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047337/does-overflowhidden-applied-to-body-work-on-iphone-safari

Comment: Thanks gents. In my particular situation (which is a bit different than what I wrote in the question), I wrapped my video tag with another div with position: absolute, overflow-x: hidden, and 100% height/width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `overflow: hidden` on the elements container.  In this case it's the body.

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This sets *all* overflow to hide (both x & y; horizontal & vertical) ergo no scrollbars at all. If - as mentioned in the OP - you need just the horizontal overflow hidden (and/or the use of vertical scrolling), use `overflow-x`.

Answer (score 2):

You're nearly there!

Setting the `overflow` of the `.example` class is *only* hiding any overflowing content *inside* of it, though.

You would need to set the `overflow` of the **parent** container of `.example`, for this to work - i.e. whatever container it is inside of.

---

As you mentioned in your OP, you want to hide horizontal scrollbars.

For this, you would need to set

```
overflow-x: hidden
```

But (as mentioned), be sure this is on the **parent** container of `.example`.

This could be the `body`, or another `div` etc. HTH.

e.g.:

```
body, .parent-container {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: @Alexandru Your edit changes the scope of the question entirely. Consider posting a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `overflow-x: hidden` in CSS to hidde only horizontal scroll.