# How to Stop background scroll on IOS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

Hello, I'm currently stuck on an issue that only happens on IOS. I have a [dropdown menu](https://imgur.com/a/Adi9c9L) that only shows on mobile & tablet mode. When the [burger icon](https://imgur.com/a/972kYGh) is clicked, it fixes the html & body, this works on all devices, except IOS, I tested this on an iPhone 5C.

Below I have listed the code that I have used stop the background scrolling. Once the [burger icon](https://imgur.com/a/972kYGh) is clicked it toggles the class noScroll. The class noScroll consists of `overflow:hidden;` which is then applied to the html & body.

I have absolutely no idea why this is not working with IOS, maybe because of the bounce scrolling? I am unsure.

The website that I am working on is [Redec](https://www.redecindustrial.com/)

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".x-btn-navbar").on("click", function() {
    $("html, body").toggleClass("noScroll");
  });
});
```

---

```
.noScroll {
    overflow: hidden;
    /* position: fixed */ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry for posting this as a solution but I don't have enough reputation to comment yet, I think you can find the solution here => [Does overflow:hidden applied to <body> work on iPhone Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047337/does-overflowhidden-applied-to-body-work-on-iphone-safari)