# How to stop background scroll in iphone on modal open

Tags: css, html

I am facing an issue with bootstrap 3 modal in iOS. Is there any working solution to prevent background scroll in iPhone, However it's working perfect on android but in iPhone whenever I open a modal and try to scroll background scroll works with a modal scroll as well.
I have tried all the possible solutions `position: fixed` not working. `overflow: hidden` is already applied. Thanks

This is the default style on the modal.

> .modal-open {
>       overflow: hidden; }

Comment: Which version of iOS?

Comment: This post might offer some help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047337/does-overflowhidden-applied-to-body-work-on-iphone-safari

Comment: Problem is on IOS 12 in landscape mode