# overflow:hidden isn't creating a new block formatting context on iOS safari

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to write a stylesheet that styles the following html

```css
body > * {
    width: 49%; /* should be 50% */
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 0px;
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<html><body>
<span><h1>some text here</h1></span>
<img src="img.png"></body></html>
```

But on iOS Safari, the bottom margin from the h1 expands past the baseline and (in the full version, that has multiple rows), pushes down the rest of the content. If I use `overflow: scroll`, this fixes it for Safari, but on other browsers messes up the view. How can I detect that this is Safari and fix it or use a different way to construct the block formatting context? I would prefer not to use Javascript, but I think that there's a chance I'll have to.

Comment: code on snippet

Comment: safari / ios won't allow it on a body tag,   make a <div> wrapper just inside the body and apply all your styles there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is NOT the block formatting context. Instead, it's the `vertical-align: text-bottom` that Safari defaults to. `vertical-align: text-top` fixes my issue by forcing the inline-blocks to align their upper baselines (which are located strictly above the text's margin or padding) rather than lower baselines which vary based on the bottom element and what margin it has, even though the margin isn't "leaking" out of the element.

Answer (score 0):

[Does overflow:hidden applied to <body> work on iPhone Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047337/does-overflowhidden-applied-to-body-work-on-iphone-safari)

```
body > * {
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: This does not fix the issue.