# overflow works differently on safari

Tags: css, sass

So this is what my program is supposed to look like:[image]

And this is what it looks like when viewed in safari:[image]

I am using scss for styling and this is the outcome. There are actually a lot of problems besides this, which from what I can surmise is from `overflow:hidden`. But from looking it up it looks like `overflow` isn't  browser sensitive.

There's actually a lot more problems besides this when viewed from safari. But I thought one of the advantages of using Sass is it automatically compensates from different kinds of browsers. Unless I did something terribly wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does overflow:hidden applied to <body> work on iPhone Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047337/does-overflowhidden-applied-to-body-work-on-iphone-safari)

Comment: Can you show working example? Seems that you are using clip path or some other stuff to cut elements diagonal