# Can not disable scrolling on ios

Tags: javascript

I have a scrollable feed on my site for user posted content.  There is a button that triggers a popup/overlay that should pause the scrolling.  I found a way to pause on a pc browser, but I am unable to pause the scrolling on my iPhone causing a weird visual glitch that shows the content behind the popup/overlay still scrolling as if it were the content ontop.

I have tried changing position to fixed, but this will not save the location of the user before they clicked the popup/overlay button.  Instead it will return the user to the top of the page.  I want to freeze the user however far down the screen they were so when they close the popup they will be able to scroll again.

```
<script>
            function NewPostPopup() {
                const noscroll = document.getElementById("newpostpopup").classList.toggle("active");
                if (noscroll) {
                    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
                } 
                else {
                    document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047337/does-overflowhidden-applied-to-body-work-on-iphone-safari       this is not answer for you?

Answer (score 0):

add this style

```css
body {
  position: fixed;
}
```

and this logic:

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

Comment: Position fixed will return to the top won't it, I have tried position fixed already, would window.scrollTo negate that?

Comment: When you don't have the necessary height to scroll, what difference does it make if the position is fixed? You are practically at the beginning and the end of the page at the same time

Comment: I explained that there is a feed of user content in the question, I do have the height to scroll.

Comment: so you ca put scroll instead auto