# body {overflow:hidden} equivalent for iOS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developping a website that, in its mobile version, is pretty similar to Instagram, with several swipable carousels.

In order to prevent scrolling while swiping, I add the class noscroll to the body while the swiping is happening.

```
.noscroll {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

However while this works perfectly on my Android phone, this does not work on any iOS devices.

I saw many people recommend adding "overflow:hidden" to the html tag but in my case anytime someone swipes the whole page just jumps back to the top.

Does anyone know a trick to prevent that ?

Comment: Does this help? It suggests to add `position:relative`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13645522/9107694